# DateTime with "UTC" Timezone to DateTime only (without the UTC Timezone) conversion in Java

Tags: java, datetime

I have this sample String "2023-02-13 06:10:45.483000 UTC" and I want to convert this into a simple DateTime format without the Timezone in Java. How do I do this in Java language?

```
String s = "2023-02-13 06:10:45.483000 UTC";
TemporalAccessor ta = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.parse(s);
Instant i = Instant.from(ta);
Date d = Date.from(i);

System.out.println(d);
```

This is my sample code and it returns an error from Java:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2023-02-13 06:10:45.483000 UTC' could not be parsed at index 10
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2052)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1880)
        at App.main(App.java:29)
```

Comment: this is not an ISO_INSTANT format - it is missing the `T` between date and time and the *time zone* is also incorrect - the `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()` method must be used for that format (or change the input to `"2023-02-13T06:10:45.483000Z"`)

Comment: The input date is retrieved from a BigQuery Timestamp data type column. Is there any way I can convert that "UTC" to that 'Z'?

Comment: What *exactly* is a “simple DateTime format”?

Comment: *I want to convert this into a simple DateTime format without the Timezone* So you want to discard key information? What datatype do you want to end up with?

Comment: You don’t want to throw away the information that the date and time are in UTC. You may want to present the date and time to the user without that information, but do keep it internally nevertheless. Just in case.

Comment: Declare `private static final DateTimeFormatter BIG_QUERY_PARSER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder() .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE) .appendLiteral(' ') .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME) .appendPattern(" zzz") .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);`. Parse using `Instant i = BIG_QUERY_PARSER.parse(s, Instant::from);`. An `Instant` is independent of time zone, just denotes a point in time, like a BigQuery timestamp.

Comment: @g00se I forgot to add more details sorry about that but I wanted to convert this into a LocalDate datatype that should end up with a value of something like "2023-02-13".

Comment: @BasilBourque I just simply wanted this sample string to become something like a LocalDate format type which would result in a value of "2023-02-13".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue using

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter BIG_QUERY_PARSER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
        .appendPattern(" zzz")
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Thank you for the comments/solutions.

Comment: Or just `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS zzz")`.